# I just re-installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 on an HP laptop. Why is it so slow?

Tags: windows-7, performance, hp-pavilion

I got a new HP laptop, went through and uninstalled all the default HP programs on there, and that caused the whole system to crash.

So I took a fresh Windows 7 Home Premium disc, and used it to first reformat the hard drive completely, and install everything fresh.

The trouble is... it is unbelievably **SLOW**. It was nowhere near this slow before I reinstalled. I've been going through and reinstalling drivers (of course), but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: If you open the task manager, are there any processes using a LOT of resources?

Comment: @Simon: No! There's practically nothing running in Task Manager!

Comment: @slhck: It's an HP Pavilion dm4-2033cl.

Comment: I'd say go to the download drivers page on the hp web site and download the chipset and graphics drivers as a start and see if that helps.  There will probably be others you'll need as well to get everything working but that's a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HP restore has a [Minimized recovery option](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02638587&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en#N121), this would have been the optimal solution rather than a clean install from non HP recovery media. This will install all the proper drivers for your HP laptop which saves a huge amount of time and headache. Minimized recovery leaves out all the crapware.

If you [made your recovery discs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867124) before you wiped the drive, you can use these to perform the HP minimized recovery.

If you did not make your recovery discs and the restore partition is still intact, you can use W7 disk management to mark the recovery partition as "Active" and reboot, the HP recovery manager should load.

If the partition is gone or damaged you will need to [order recovery discs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Device Manager and see if you have and undetected devices.  You might have missed some important drivers - especially the motherboards chipset drivers.